# Get links of a html document in order

Tags: c#, html, regex, webbrowser-control, html-agility-pack

I want to get all the links of a HTML document. This isn't a problem, but apparently it puts all the links in an alphabetic order before storing them in an array one by one. I want to have the links in original order (not in alphabetic).

So is there any possibility to get the first found link, store it, then the second one,...? I already tried using HtmlAgilityPack and the Webbrowser-Control methods, but both order them alphabetically. The original order is important for later purposes.

I heard that it might be possible with Regex, but I've found enough answers, where they say that you shouldn't use it for HTML parsing. So how can I do it?

Here's the Webbrowser-Control code, I tried to use to get the links and store them into an array:

```
    private void btnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlWindow mainFrame = webFl.Document.Window.Frames["mainFrame"];
        HtmlElementCollection links = mainFrame.Document.Links;

        foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
        {
            string linkText = link.OuterHtml;
            if (linkText.Contains("puzzle"))
            {
                arr[i] = linkText;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance,
Opak

Comment: try iterating with a for loop, not a foreach. It might work

Comment: Of course not it wouldn't, foreach doesn't automagically break order of elements . . .

Comment: What kind of page are you trying to work with? Must it work with all pages or do you have a specific target in mind? Because if you can stick to only XHTML pages then you could just treat them as xml and use linq to XML for this, would bypass additional libraries and make very simple code

Comment: As far as I know neither HtmlAgilityPack nor HtmlDocument order elements before returning. Are you absolutely sure order does not match HTML and you don't have some sort of `OrderBy`/`Sort` code somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the correct order by walking the DOM tree using [HTML DOM API](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html). The following code does this. Note, I use `dynamic` to access DOM API. That's because `WebBrowser`'s `HtmlElement.FirstChild`/`HtmlElement.NextSibling` don't work for this purpose, as they return `null` for DOM text nodes.

```
private void btnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Action<object> walkTheDom = null;
    var links = new List<object>();

    // element.FirstChild / NextSibling don't work as they stop at DOM text nodes

    walkTheDom = (element) =>
    {
        dynamic domElement = element;
        if (domElement.tagName == "A")
            links.Add(domElement);
        for (dynamic child = domElement.firstChild; child != null; child = child.nextSibling)
        {
            if (child.nodeType == 1) // Element node?
                walkTheDom(child);
        }
    };

    walkTheDom(this.webBrowser.Document.Body.DomElement);

    string html = links.Aggregate(String.Empty, (a, b) => a + ((dynamic)b).outerHtml + Environment.NewLine);
    MessageBox.Show(html);
}
```

**[UPDATE]** If you really need to get a list of `HtmlElement` objects for `<A>` tags, instead of `dynamic` native elements, that's still possible with a little trick using `GetElementById`:

```
private void btnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // element.FirstChild / NextSibling don't work because they stop on DOM text nodes

    var links = new List<HtmlElement>();
    var document = this.webBrowser.Document;
    dynamic domDocument = document.DomDocument;
    Action<dynamic> walkTheDom = null;

    walkTheDom = (domElement) =>
    {
        if (domElement.tagName == "A")
        {
            // get HtmlElement for the found <A> tag
            string savedId = domElement.id;
            string uniqueId = domDocument.uniqueID;
            domElement.id = uniqueId;
            links.Add(document.GetElementById(uniqueId));
            if (savedId != null)
                domElement.id = savedId;
            else
                domElement.removeAttribute("id");
        }
        for (var child = domElement.firstChild; child != null; child = child.nextSibling)
        {
            if (child.nodeType == 1) // is an Element node?
                walkTheDom(child);
        }
    };

    // walk the DOM for <A> tags
    walkTheDom(domDocument.body);

    // show the found tags
    string combinedHtml = links.Aggregate(String.Empty, (html, element) => html + element.OuterHtml + Environment.NewLine);
    MessageBox.Show(combinedHtml);
}
```